# Windows Media Player 11 Codec Installation

Tags: installation, windows-media-player, codec, sms, video-codecs

Scenario: Some of our users are trying to play DVD's or other media files and are getting a message telling them that they are missing a codec. Since there are not admins they cannot install the codec. Instead our Help Desk has been getting calls and to resolve this issue they installed VLC player.

Question: Is there a way I can use SCCM(SMS) to install the codecs required to play DVD's. I'd like to stay away from having to buy a DVD Decoder if possible.

Note: SCCM stands for Microsoft Systems Center Configuration Manager.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just have to find the appropriate codecs and make sure that they can be distributed silently.  Lately I've been finding the [LAV Filters](https://code.google.com/p/lavfilters/) to be very good.  I don't know if the installer can be easily distributed via silent installation, but there's a zip file distribution that should be trivial to deploy (copy into place and register codecs with `regsvr32.exe`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried installing it on a test machine and it said it installed correctly but I wasn't able to play the DVD(VOB File) even after I restarted the machine.

Comment: Hrm -- I'm surprised that it's lacking a vob splitter.  Now, I *have* used [ffdshow-tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) on XP to enable DVD decoding in WMP.

Answer (score -1):

Install VLC player from www.videolan.org? It plays DVD, BD, DVB-S, DVB-T, MKV and all other sorts of MPEG without polluting 99% of other desktops.

Comment: That was not the question though. They already know that they can install VLC.